Number of irreducible polynomials over finite field $F$ and $\mathbb{Q}$
I have a question whether set of all irreducible polynomials over a finite field $F$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.
I have no idea what to do with the case of finite field $F$. Speaking of $\mathbb{Q}$ case: I think that the answer is yes because $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ is countable $\forall n$. I've searched the finite field case and found out that there is a formula to calculate the exact number of such polynomials, but it's too difficult to prove (I just want to understand why there are countably/finitely many polynomials in finite field case)
I'm a beginner in field theory so I'm sorry if this question is obvious.

I mean, if $F$ is finite then $F[x]$ is a countable set, so there can't be an uncountable number of irreducible polynomials for sure. The only nontrivial question is whether there are infinitely many irreducible polynomials. The answer is yes, it's a standard result in field theory that any finite field contains an irreducible polynomial of any degree.

To complement Mark's comment, see e.g. this question & answer

@Mark,  (if $F$ is finite then $F[x]$ is countable): how can we strictly show it? How do you numerate them?

@JaneDoe When we want to prove a set is countable, we rarely do it directly by the definition. We use different theorems. A countable union of finite sets is countable. (for any $n$, there are clearly finitely many polynomials of degree $n$, if $F$ is finite)

This is in response to the comment-question of how to show:

if $F$ is finite, then $F[x]$ is countable

Notice that an element of $F[x]$ has finite length. Let us pick an $f \in F[x]$ and represent it as the function defined by:
$$x \mapsto a_0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$$
You can have more terms, but we'll use this just for the idea of the proof.
In the polynomial written out above, each $a_k \in F$, which means there are countably many of them. (If $F$ is finite, then there are finitely many; but you have also asked about the case in which $F = \mathbb{Q}$, which is countably infinite.)
Since $F$ is countable, there exists a map $g: F \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that takes elements of $F$ as input and gives natural numbers as outputs.
The idea here will be to consider the terms in order, beginning with the constant term and moving upwards in degree of the terms, and associate them with the prime numbers $2,3,5, \ldots$.
In particular, let us associate with the polynomial written above the natural number:
$$2^{g(a_0)}\cdot3^{g(a_1)}\cdot5^{g(a_2)}\cdot7^{g(a_3)}$$
This gives an injective (aka one-to-one) function from $F[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, which means that $F[x]$ is countable.
To write out the more general definition of our map, we just need to look at the example and figure out how to write it out in sum and product notation:
For any element of $F[x]$ written as
$$f := \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_{n}x^{n}$$
we write $P(k)$ to mean the $k^\text{th}$ prime and map $f$ to
$$\prod_{n=1}^{k}P(n)^{g(a_n)}$$
Since we have an injective function from $F[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, the claim of countability follows.
